# SonarQube no longer detects S1166 (Exception handlers should preserve the original exceptions)

Tags: java, sonarqube

In SonarQube 6.1 I got 125 such issues on one project of mine. However in versions 7.0 and 6.7.1 I suddenly got exactly 0 on the same code with no changes.

What happened?

Here's a typical example of code that should get that issue, but didn't get it:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Load balance test faild with exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: What is the version of SonarJava in both of your cases ? because there does not seem to have been a lot of modification on that rule recently : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/commits/0d545786c262e5ec0aa4e14f0763ef98ec670c37/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/CatchUsesExceptionWithContextCheck.java

Comment: Do you use a quality profile configured by yourself or provided by SonarSource?

Comment: @agabrys I use the unmodified SonarSource package. I only started it up and then did a 'mvn clean install sonar:sonar'

Comment: @benzonico where can I see the SonarJava-version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [S1166 Exception handlers should preserve the original exceptions](https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/default/rules?open=squid%3AS1166&q=S1166) is disabled in quality profiles provided by SonarSource.

Some time ago (I don't remember in which version exactly) SonarSource developers made those quality profiles as read-only. It probably means that you:

1. modified `Sonar way` profile → S1166 has been enabled
2. analyzed code → issues have been created
3. upgrade SonarQube → quality profiles have been restored and marked as read-only
4. analyzed code → issues have been closed, because the rule is disabled

You have to create your custom quality profile and enable that rule.

Comment: It was completely unthinkable to me that they could disable this test, but so they had :-/